# Overridden save() method behavior not using super().save() method

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a customized save() method that creates intermediate models if the conditions match:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    integervalue = models.PositiveIntegerField(...)
    some_field = models.CharField(...)
    related_objects = models.ManyToManyField('OtherModel', through='IntermediaryModel')
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None: # if a new object is being created - then
            super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # save instance first to obtain PK for later
            if self.some_field == 'Foo': 
                for otherModelInstance in OtherModel.objects.all(): # creates instances of intermediate model objects for all OtherModels
                    new_Intermediary_Model_instance = IntermediaryModel.objects.create(person = self, other = otherModelInstance)
        super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs) #should be called upon exiting the cycle
```

However, if editing **an existing** Person both through shell and through admin interface - if I alter integervalue of some existing Person - the changes are not saved. As if for some reason last super(...).save() is not called.

However, if I were to add else block to the outer if, like:

```
        if self.pk is None:
            ...
        else:
            super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

the save() would work as expected for existing objects - changed integervalue is saved in database.

Am I missing something, or this the correct behavior? Is "self.pk is None" indeed a valid indicator that object is just being created in Django?

**P.S.** I am currently rewriting this into signals, though this behavior still puzzles me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers - after careful examination I may safely conclude that I tripped over my own two feet.

After careful examination and even a trip with pdb, I found that the original code had mixed indentation - \t instead of \s{4} before the last super().save().

Answer (score 1):

If your `pk is None`, super's `save()` is called twice, which I think is not you expect. Try these changes:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_created = True if not self.pk else False
        super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if is_created and self.some_field == 'Foo': 
            for otherModelInstance in OtherModel.objects.all(): 
                new_Intermediary_Model_instance = IntermediaryModel.objects.create(person = self, other = otherModelInstance)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not such a good idea to override `save()` method. Django is doing a lot of stuff behind the scene to make sure that model objects are saved as they expected. If you do it in incorrectly it would yield bizarre behavior and hard to debug.

Please check [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#pre-save), it's convenient way to access your model object information and status. They provide useful parameters like `instance`, `created` and `updated_fields` to fit specially your need to check the object.

Comment: I actually am rewriting this bit into signals, thank you for reminding - will add this as P.S. to the question. The question is more of "why does this work the way it works" question.

Comment: The best bet is to put a pdb debugger inside and step through(I assume you know how to, but it's almost trivial to learn if you don't). I cannot visually debug your code. Maybe Alex's answer would help, but as I said, it's very easy to mess up by overriding `save()` method.